# How to transform a ellipse to a rect in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, key, p5.js

So I´m trying to code something that a shape transforms to another one, if a specific key is pressed. So far I´m stuck at the first shape. How can I write, that my "var musculus" changes to function flexor, or extensor on keyTyped?

```js
var musculus;

function draw() {
  musculus = ellipse(30, 30, 20, 20);

  function keyTyped() {
    if (key === 'a') {
      musculus = flexor;
    } else if (key === 'b') {
      musculus = extensor;
    }
  }
}

function flexor() {
  ellipse(56, 46, 55, 55);
}

function extensor() {
  square(30, 20, 55, 20);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: where is listener for keypress

Comment: Using p5, so the `keyTyped` is the listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is close to working, you just need to make a few changes.

1. Remove the line `musculus = ellipse(30, 30, 20, 20);` in `draw()`.
   Draw is run every frame so musculus keeps getting set to `ellipse(30, 30, 20, 20)`
2. `musculus` is set but never used, add `musculus;` into `draw()` so it is used each on frame.
3. Move `keyTyped()` outside of `draw()` so P5js can see and use it.
4. `keyTypes()` is correct but you need to set `musculus` to the function not just the function name. Just add `()` to each function name. ie. `musculus = flexor();`

There are definitely a lot of improvements you can make to this script but you're off to a good start.
**Fixed code**

```
var musculus;

function draw() {
  musculus;
}

function keyTyped() {
  if (key === 'a') {
    musculus = flexor();
  } else if (key === 'b') {
    musculus = extensor();
  }
}

function flexor() {
  ellipse(56, 46, 55, 55);
}

function extensor() {
  square(30, 20, 55, 20);
}
```

**Better fix**
In my re-write, I set the value of `musculus` to a word(aka. string) which is used in `draw()` to call the corresponding function in an `if statement`. I'm also using `background('white')` to clear the screen before drawing the new frame.

```js
var musculus;
    
function draw() {
  background(255);
  if (musculus === 'flexor') {
    flexor();
  } else if (musculus === 'extensor') {
    extensor();
  }
}
    
function keyTyped() {
  if (key === 'a') {
    musculus = 'flexor';
  } else if (key === 'b') {
    musculus = 'extensor';
  }
}
    
function flexor() {
  ellipse(56, 46, 55, 55);
}

function extensor() {
  square(30, 20, 55, 20);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make `musculus` its own function which you can call to draw your circle. You can then use a global variable called `currentShape` which stores a reference to the current shape you want to draw (ie a function which draws your ellipse). When you want to change your shape (in the `keyPress`) you can do so reassigning `currentShape` to be set to a new function which will draw a new shape.

Also note that in p5js, your `keyTyped()` function should sit outside of any of your other functions.

```js
var currentShape = musculus;
function draw() {
  background(255); // draw background (remove any previously drawn shapes)
  currentShape();
}

function keyTyped() {
  if (key === 'a') {
    currentShape = flexor;
  } else if (key === 'b') {
    currentShape = extensor;
  }
}

function musculus() {
  ellipse(30, 30, 20, 20);
}

function flexor() {
  ellipse(56, 46, 55, 55);
}

function extensor() {
  square(30, 20, 55, 20);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```